# Distribution function of area of a triangle

Tags: probability

Choose a point $P=(x,y)$ uniformly on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$, and consider the area $Z$ of the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(x,1)$ and $(1,y)$.

I want to find the distribution function of $Z$.

Clearly $Z=1-(1+xy)/2$.

Therefore,

$$F(z)=P(Z\leq z)=P(1-(1+xy)/2\leq z)=P(xy\geq 1-2z)$$

It is the next step that I have problem with. According to the textbook,

$$P(xy\geq 1-2z)=\int_{1-2z}^1 \int_{(1-2z)/x}^1 dydx$$

Can someone help me understand this step? In particular how to find
the limits of integration in this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x$ and $y$ are chosen from uniform distributions, we can draw a graph showing where the desired event occurs:
[image]
Now the integration limits become clear. In the variable $x$, we start from $1-2z$, where $y=1$, and end at 1. For a given $x$ within this range, we let $y$ vary from $\frac{1-2z}x$ to 1, thus yielding the given double integral.